# Terraform depend existing module resource on newly created resources

Tags: terraform, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

This can be viewed as a "generic" Terraform question.

I have a module (`vm-instances`) used to create my virtual machines. This module has a variable `boot_volume_key_id`, which has the `id` of the KMS key id if it exists. This key is created in another configuration file if a local variable `create_kms_key` is set.
I'm using the newly created KMS key to update the `boot_volume` of my exisiting, and in order to use this KMS key for the boot volume a identity policy for managing the boot volume is created. The `oci_kms_key` is referenced in a statment in the `oci_identity_policy` E.g simplified configuration files:

*kms.tf*

```
resource "oci_kms_key" "boot_volume_key"{
  count = local.create_kms_key ? 1 : 0
  ...
}

resource "oci_identity_policy" "boot_volume"{
  count = local.create_kms_key ? 1 : 0
  ...
  statement =  [
     Allow ... where target.key.id = ${oci_kms_key.boot_volume_key.0.id}
  ]
}
```

*main.tf*

```
module "instances" {
  source = "./module/vm-instances"
  ...
  boot_volume =  local.create_kms_key ? oci_kms_key.boot_volume_key.0.id : null
}
```

**Problem**: I get a *404-NotAuthorizedOrNotFound UpdateVolumeKMS* after first `terraform apply`, however this works after second apply. I believe this is because the identity policy takes some time to be "functioning".

How can I avoid this problem? I've looked at options like `depends_on` and `lifecycle`-metablock `ignore_changes`.

1. Problem with using `depends_on` is if I depend my entire `vm-instances` module on the identity policy, when I run `terraform plan` it seems like my instances are gonna get recreated, something I do not want.
2. Problem with `lifecycle`'s `ignore_changes` is that my virtual machines won't get updated when I introduce the KMS key into the configuration file.
3. Terraform `time_sleep` slows down Terraform configuration unecessary.

Comment: Is the `oci_kms_key` referenced in the `oci_identity_policy` resource in any way? Also, have you used `depends_on` between the modules and that had caused the recreation? Is the KMS part outside of the module or a part of another module?

Comment: @MarkoE, no. This is the first introduction of `depends_on` into my setup. There's no reference between `oci_kms_key` and `oci_identity_policy`.

Comment: @MarkoE, sorry. `oci_kms_key` is indeed used in `oci_identity_policy` statement !

Comment: Would you mind adding that to the question as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [`oci_identity_policy`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/oracle/oci/latest/docs/resources/identity_policy) can take up to 10seconds:

> New policies take effect typically within 10 seconds.

So indeed even if you set an explicit dependency with `depends_on` or have an implicit one by just using attributes from `oci_identity_policy.boot_volume` you would still need to wait for that duration.

I suggest either filing an issue in OCI provider's repository so they implement this "readiness" check in the provider, or using workarounds like [`time_sleep`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/time/latest/docs/resources/sleep):

```
resource "oci_identity_policy" "boot_volume"{
  count = local.create_kms_key ? 1 : 0
  ...
}
resource "time_sleep" "wait_for_identity_policy" {
  depends_on = [oci_identity_policy.boot_volume]

  create_duration = "15s"
}

resource "SOMETHING" "next" {
  depends_on = [time_sleep.wait_for_identity_policy]
}
```

Comment: I should update my question to include `time_sleep` as I'm aware of this, however this slows down my Terraform configuration unecessary.

Comment: The delay is on OCI itself so Terraform would need to wait for `oci_identity_policy` anyways, you either use `time_sleep` or try creating couple of dependant  `null_ressource`, which would achieve the same result of "waiting" for OC

Comment: Do I need to wait `15s` every `terraform apply`, or only when the `oci_identity_policy` does not exists?

Comment: No it won't run everytime, it waits only when `oci_identity_policy` changes

Comment: I'll accept it....